# I'm able to ssh into host, but not to access it from browser - No route to host

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, lan

I have a setup on my home lan like this:

- router with OpenWRT OS which also acts as DHCP server
- host machine - Debian Wheezy
- guest OS on the host machine - CentOS 7 which only has one NIC which is setup as bridged

  - internet works from this machine
  - i can ping the host machine and the router also

I can connect to the guest machine from the host with ssh, but if I start my dev web server (i tried starting the dev server on port 3000, 8080 and 5000 ) on guest, I can't connect to it from within the browser on host.

I looked for firewall/iptables/selinux on guest and I think none is started.

What else should I try?

Comment: The firewall service is called firewalld on CentOS 7. I have been burned by this before.

Comment: if you add that as an answer I'll accept it - service firewalld stop solved the issue

Comment: Would it be better to fix the firewall (rule) rather than stop it altogether?

Comment: the VM is my dev machine - I'm not really concerned with security on it. But indeed - the correct solution is to configure the firewall instead of disabling it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As people commented you would be better to add the rule as an exception and restart the service:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp
systemctl restart firewalld.service
```